# After call pg_restore I can not access the database through pgpool2

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I wrote script for daily backup DB. Simply steps:

1. dump

```
pg_dump -Fc --blobs --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --encoding UTF8 --verbose -h localhost -p 5433 -U username DB -f /home/db.backup
```

2. drop and create daily DB

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U username -At -d DB -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DBdaily;"
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U username -At -d DB -c "CREATE DATABASE DBdaily;"
```

3. restore DB

```
pg_restore -d DBdaily -h localhost -p 5433 -U username /home/db.backup
```

If I want to access to DBdaily by pgadmin I get an error:
[image]

I testing access to DBdaily after DROP and CREATE and it's working, but after pg_restore not working. This error means something with backend, but I don't know how can I resolve it.

Version of pgpool2 is 3.6.7, postgresql is 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used pgAdmin version 4 everything works.
Problem is in pgAdmin version 3, I think.